# Custom STL Allocator with a custom constructor

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

I'm using the STL allocator mentioned [here](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/memory/myalloc.hpp.html). 
The only change I'm making is that I'm inheriting from a base class called Object, and I use base class' new and delete functions for allocation.

```
    class MyAlloc :public Object{
    ......
    }
```

I want to use the parameterized constructor of the base class which will be based on parameter sent to the STLAllocator, which would be something like this.

```
    MyAlloc(A *a) : Object(a) {
    ... }
```

And then use this constructor like :

```
   A *a = new A();
   std::vector<int,MyAlloc<int> (a) > v;
```

I'm not able to achieve this. It is resulting in compilation error :
'a'cannot appear in a constant-expression
  template argument 2 is invalid
Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You specify the *type* of the allocator as a template argument and, if you don't want a default-constructed one, a *value* as a constructor argument:

```
std::vector<int,MyAlloc<int>> v((MyAlloc<int>(a)));
```

Note that I added an extra pair of parentheses to avoid the ["most vexing parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). In this case, we can't avoid that using brace-initialisation, since that will try to use the initialiser list to populate the vector.

Comment: @gx_: Good point; I only parsed it with my brain, which is a bit buggy today.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. solutions works fine with std::vector but is not working with std::map. I have used it in the same way : std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, 
    MyAlloc<std::pair<const std::string,std::string> > > 
    x ((MyAlloc<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>(a))); Results here : http://ideone.com/C8hY19

Comment: @codinonwheels: Your allocator needs to meet the allocator requirements described in C++11 17.6.3.5 (or C++98 20.1.5, if you're stuck in the past). `pointer` is one of several members and nested types that it needs to provide.

Comment: Actually, looks like my allocator satisfies the requirements. I know this because if I don't have the value as construct argument, it works fine. The error crops in once I have a value as construct argument. Also, I wanted to know the value passed is right or not..! Please bear me.. I'm learning allocators.