# How to use Stl custom allocator that needs non-default constructor

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to use stl with a custom allocator that needs to use non-default constructor. I follow the example in this link 
[Custom STL Allocator with a custom constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575746/custom-stl-allocator-with-a-custom-constructor) and get something like this:

```
void * start = new uint8_t[100];
Engine::BlockAllocator block_allocator = Engine::BlockAllocator(start, 100, 8, 8);
std::vector<uint64_t, Engine::StlAllocator<uint64_t>> a((Engine::StlAllocator<uint64_t>(&block_allocator)) );
```

My StlAllocator class

```
template <class T>
class StlAllocator {
public:
    using value_type = T;

    StlAllocator(IAllocator * allocator):_allocator(allocator) {}

    StlAllocator(StlAllocator && allocator): _allocator(allocator._allocator) {
        allocator._allocator = nullptr;
    }
    // need to have this specific signature to work with stl
    value_type* allocate(std::size_t n) {
        AllocateArray<value_type>(*_allocator, n);
    }
    // need to have this specific signature to work with stl
    void deallocate(value_type* p, std::size_t) noexcept {
        DeallocateArray<value_type>(*_allocator, p);
    }

    //TODO: Delete these constructors after I figured out what wrong with the custom allocator
    StlAllocator(const StlAllocator& allocator):_allocator(allocator._allocator) {}
    StlAllocator& operator=(const StlAllocator& allocator) {
        _allocator = allocator._allocator;
    }

private:
    // 8 bytes
    IAllocator * _allocator;
};

template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(StlAllocator<T> const&, StlAllocator<U> const&) noexcept {
    return true;
}

template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(StlAllocator<T> const& x, StlAllocator<U> const& y) noexcept {
    return !(x == y);
}
```

IAllocator class

```
class IAllocator {
    template <class T> friend T* OperatorNew(IAllocator & allocator);
    template <class T> friend void OperatorDelete(IAllocator & allocator, T * object);
    template <class T> friend T* AllocateNew(IAllocator & allocator);
    template <class T> friend T* AllocateNew(IAllocator & allocator, T & t);
    template <class T> friend T* AllocateNew(IAllocator & allocator, T && t);
    template <class T> friend void DeallocateDelete(IAllocator & allocator, T * object);
    template <class T> friend T* AllocateArray(IAllocator & allocator, size_t length);
    template <class T> friend void DeallocateArray(IAllocator & allocator, T * array);
public:
    IAllocator(void * start, uint64_t size);
    IAllocator(IAllocator&& other);
    void * GetStart() const;
    uint64_t GetNumAlloc() const;
    uint64_t GetUsed() const;
    uint64_t GetTotalSize() const;
    uint64_t GetFree() const;
    void Reset();
    virtual ~IAllocator();
private:
    virtual void * Allocate(uint64_t size, uint8_t alignment) = 0;
    virtual void Deallocate(void * ptr) = 0;

protected:
    // virtual pointer table 8 bytes 
    // 8 bytes
    uint64_t _used;
    // 8 bytes
    uint64_t _total_size;
    // 8 bytes
    uint64_t _num_alloc;
    // 8 bytes
    void * _start;
};

template <class T> T* OperatorNew(IAllocator & allocator) {
    void * ptr = allocator.Allocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T));
    if (ptr == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Allocator has run out of space\n";
        return nullptr;
    }
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);
}

template <class T> void OperatorDelete(IAllocator & allocator, T * object) {
    assert(object != nullptr);
    allocator.Deallocate(object);
}



template <class T> T* AllocateNew(IAllocator & allocator) {
    void * ptr = allocator.Allocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T));
    if (ptr == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Allocator has run out of space\n";
        return nullptr;
    }
    /*std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "Allocate in thread " << this_id << "\n";*/
    return new (ptr) T;
}

template <class T> T* AllocateNew(IAllocator & allocator, T & t) {
    void * ptr = allocator.Allocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T));
    if (ptr == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Allocator has run out of space\n";
        return nullptr;
    }
    /*std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "Allocate in thread " << this_id << "\n";*/
    return new (ptr) T(t);
}

template <class T> T* AllocateNew(IAllocator & allocator, T && t) {
    void * ptr = allocator.Allocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T));
    if (ptr == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Allocator has run out of space\n";
        return nullptr;
    }
    /*std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "Allocate in thread " << this_id << "\n";*/
    return new (ptr) T(std::move(t));
}

template <class T> void DeallocateDelete(IAllocator & allocator, T * object) {
    assert(object != nullptr);
    object->~T();
    /*std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "Deallocate in thread " << this_id << "\n";*/
    allocator.Deallocate(object); 
}

template <class T> T* AllocateArray(IAllocator & allocator, size_t length) {
    size_t header_size = sizeof(size_t) / sizeof(T); // find header_size as a multiple of T, an array only needs one header
    if (sizeof(size_t) % sizeof(T) > 0) {
        header_size += 1;
    }
    void * alloc_ptr = allocator.Allocate(sizeof(T)*(header_size + length), alignof(T)); // allocate enough size for an array 
    if (alloc_ptr == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Allocator has run out of space\n";
        return nullptr;
    }
    T* p = reinterpret_cast<T*>(alloc_ptr) + header_size; // the returned ptr is at an offset of headerSize from the address returned by allocator
    *(reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(p) - 1) = length; // set the header to the length of the array
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        new (p + i) T; // construct objects in the memory 
    }
    /*std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "Allocate in thread " << this_id << "\n";*/
    return p;
}

template <class T> void DeallocateArray(IAllocator & allocator, T * array) {
    assert(array != nullptr);
    size_t * header_ptr = (reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(array) - 1); // find address of header
    size_t length = *header_ptr;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        (array + i)->~T(); // call destructor of objects
    }
    size_t header_size = sizeof(size_t) / sizeof(T); // find header_size as a multiple of T
    if (sizeof(size_t) % sizeof(T) > 0) {
        header_size += 1;
    }
    /*std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "Deallocate in thread " << this_id << "\n";*/
    allocator.Deallocate(array - header_size); // deallocate using the address returned by allocation, which is computed by array - header_size
}
```

BlockAllocator.h

```
class BlockAllocator: public IAllocator {
public:
    BlockAllocator(void * start, uint64_t size, uint64_t block_size, uint8_t block_alignment);
    BlockAllocator(BlockAllocator&& other);
    ~BlockAllocator() override;
    BlockAllocator(const BlockAllocator&) = delete;
    BlockAllocator& operator=(const BlockAllocator&) = delete;
private: 
    void * Allocate(uint64_t size, uint8_t alignment) override;
    void Deallocate(void * ptr) override;
private:
    // 8 bytes virtual table function pointer
    // 32 bytes IAllocator
    // 8 bytes
    uint64_t _block_size;
    // 8 bytes
    void ** _free_list;
    // 1 bytes
    uint8_t _block_alignment;
    // 7 bytes
    uint8_t _padding[7];

};
```

BlockAllocator.cpp (this is a stripped down minimal version)

```
BlockAllocator::BlockAllocator(void * start, uint64_t size, uint64_t block_size, uint8_t block_alignment): IAllocator(start, size), 
    _block_size(block_size), 
    _block_alignment(block_alignment) {
}

BlockAllocator::BlockAllocator(BlockAllocator&& other):IAllocator(std::move(other)), 
    _block_size(other._block_size), 
    _free_list(other._free_list), 
    _block_alignment(other._block_alignment) {}

BlockAllocator::~BlockAllocator() {
    _free_list = nullptr;
}

void * BlockAllocator::Allocate(uint64_t size, uint8_t alignment) {
    void * ptr = operator new(size);
    return ptr; 
}

void BlockAllocator::Deallocate(void * ptr) {
    delete ptr;
}
```

I am using c++17 on visual studio. The error I got is this

```
Error   C2664   'Engine::StlAllocator<_Newfirst>::StlAllocator(const Engine::StlAllocator<_Newfirst> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Engine::StlAllocator<uint64_t>' to 'Engine::IAllocator *'
```

Comment: What is `ptr` ?

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: All constructuctors of STL containers take as a last argument `const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()`, see here for [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). That can be used if the allocator has no default constructor.

Comment: @sv90 so you are suggesting I make my allocator variable const?

Comment: @HenryWise no. It is only passed by const reference and copy-constructed into the container

Comment: @sv90 but that is exactly what I am doing isnt it?

Comment: Are you getting this error with or without `StlAllocator(const StlAllocator& allocator)` constructor? The `TODO` comment appears to suggest that the error may be going away once it's added. An allocator is indeed [required](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) to be copyable, so you need that constructor.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I get the same error even if I have copy constructor for StlAllocator

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on. Not only is `Allocator<T>` required to be constructible from `Allocator<T>` - it's also required to be constructible from `Allocator<U>` for any type `U`. The container is allowed to "rebind" the allocator to obtain an allocator for types other than `T` (e.g. `std::list<T>` would generally need to allocate some internal type `Node<T>`, not `T` itself). In your case, the container rebound `StlAllocator<uint64_t>` to obtain an instance of the allocator capable of allocating some internal type `_Newfirst`, then tried to construct the latter from the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StlAllocator<T>` doesn't meet [allocator requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator). In particular, it is required to be constructible from `StlAllocator<U>` for any type `U`, not just from `StlAllocator<T>`.

The error suggests that the container using your `StlAllocator<uint64_t>` actually needs an allocator for some internal type (named `_Newfirst`), and so tries and fails to construct the latter from the former.

Comment: How do you suggest I fix this? Should i do something similar to this? "
    template <class U> struct rebind { typedef stl_allocator<U> other; };
    template <class U> stl_allocator(const stl_allocator<U>&){}" . Cause I see many examples online that dont need this.

Comment: You don't need to provide an explicit `rebind`; modern compilers can rebind implicitly. You do indeed need to provide a templated constructor from `StlAllocator<U>`. [The example you cite](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/memory/myalloc.hpp.html) does provide such a constructor.